# Python tox dependencies installation output

Tags: python, testing, tox

Is it possibile with `tox` to avoid the redirect of the output to a file when installing dependencies with `pip`? I want to see what's being installed so I would like to log to stdout instead of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by adding the changing the `install_command` in the `tox.ini` as follows:

```
install_command = ./install_deps {opts} {packages}
```

where `install_deps` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script is used as `install_command` for `tox` in order to log to stdout
# the requirements that are being installed.

pip install $@ | tee /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to see what's been installed for each run, what about using `pip freeze`? You can add it to the `commands` section and it will dump the installed packages in requirements format.

```
commands =
    pip freeze
    ... rest of your commands here.
```

I often use this strategy for doing something like `python echo_versions.py` where `echo_versions.py` is a small script that shows the versions of packages that I'm interested in for each run - just to ensure that the expected package is installed.